# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context in main method

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

I am showing an error in my main method for this statement: 
// non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new PieChart());
```

I thought this would be as easy as loading a content pane and adding the PieChart class to it. I spent several hours today and was hoping I could get help with this issue. I have 10 weeks experience with Java and haven't wandered out of my depth until now. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
Here is my PieChart program:


package iapiechart;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class IAPieChart{

    double arcValue;        // passes a value for the calculation of the arc.
    Color marker;            // holds value for color (expressed as an integer 

    public IAPieChart(double value, Color color){

        this.arcValue = value;
        this.marker = color;
    }


    public class PieChart extends JComponent { 

        IAPieChart[] pieValue = {new IAPieChart(5, Color.green),
                                new IAPieChart(33, Color.orange),
                                new IAPieChart(20, Color.blue),
                                new IAPieChart(15, Color.red)

        };

        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            drawPie((Graphics2D) g, getBounds(),  pieValue);

        }

        void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, IAPieChart[] pieValue){

            double sum = 0.0D;
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++) {

                sum += pieValue[i].arcValue;
            }

            double endPoint =  0.0D;
            int arcStart = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++){

                endPoint = (int) (endPoint * 360 / sum);
                int radius = (int) (pieValue[i].arcValue * 360/ sum);
                g.setColor(pieValue[i].marker);
                g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, arcStart, radius);
                radius += pieValue[i].arcValue;
            }

        }
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new PieChart()); // This is where the error occurs. 
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }
 }
```

Comment: To those attempting to close this question as a duplicate: This question is about making the inner class static, and not a method static, so this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a static method `main` you are attempting to instantiate an inner class `PieChart` that is not static -- declare it static.

```
public static class PieChart extends JComponent {
```

If you were to keep `PieChart` non-static, then you would need an instance of `IAPieChart` to create an instance of `PieChart`, and you don't have an instance of `IAPieChart` in `main`.

Comment: rgettman: I owe you a case of your favorite beverage. I spent 9 hours on this one issue. Just thanking you wouldn't be enough. I will share this with others, my friend.

Comment: Thanks again Gettman. You guys were a real help last week. This isn't complete but it did meet the requirements and then some. I have a basis and a good understanding of JApplet thanks to your help. 

http://www.apexsouthwest.com/PieChart/

Answer (score 0):

Since you create the IaPieChart in the PieChart class your code should be something like:

```
public class PieChart extend JComponent
{

    static class IaPieChart(..)
    {
    }
}
```

That is your IaPieChart class is really a helper class for the PieChart class so it should be defined within that class, not the other way around.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access non-static stuff from a static member, as discussed a couple hours ago.-

["non static method cannot be referenced from a static context" JPA Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979278/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-jpa-java)